# How does iPython Parallel's map function execute a function?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, ipython

I'm using ipython's parallel features:

```
client = Client()
client.direct_view().use_dill()

def hostname():
    import socket
    return socket.gethostname()

# For joblib, we only want one client per host. 
joblib_clients = dict(zip(map(lambda x: client[x].apply_sync(hostname), client.ids), client.ids))
lview_joblib = client.load_balanced_view(targets=joblib_clients.values())
dview = client.direct_view()
```

I also read in data from disk locally and on each engine

```
%%px --local

store = pd.HDFStore(data_file, 'r')
rows = store.select('results', ['cv_score_mean > 0'])
rows = rows.sort('cv_score_mean', ascending=False)
rows['results_index'] = rows.index
data_model = store.select('data_model')
p = re.compile('_coef$')
feature_set =  rows.filter(regex='_coef$').dropna(axis=1, how='all').rename(columns=lambda x: p.sub('',x)).columns
```

Then I define and instantiate a class on all the engines (but not locally).

```
%%px 
class DataRegression(object):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs): ...
       ...
   def regress_z_scores(self, **kwargs):
       ... 
regressions = DataRegression(data_model, feature_set)
```

There are a few ways I can think to call this function through my load-balanced view:

1) Through a lambda function:

```
# What exactly is this lambda function passing to the lview? 
ar = lview_joblib.map(lambda run: regressions.regress_z_scores(run), runs)
```

2)  By trying to invoke the function directly:

```
# This fails with a NameError, because regressions.regress_z_scores is not defined
ar = lview_joblib.map(regressions.regress_z_scores, runs)
```

3) By creating the regressions object locally as well:

```
%%px --local
class DataRegression(object):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs): ...
       ...
   def regress_z_scores(self, **kwargs):
       ... 
regressions = DataRegression(data_model, feature_set)

# And invoking it through the name. 
ar = lview_joblib.map(regressions.regress_z_scores, runs)
# Does this mean that the local object gets pickled and passed to the client each time?
```

In each of these cases, how is the load-balanced view's map function actually executing this function call? Is there a best practice?